# How do I run a shell script with export command in crontab?

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I have a shell script that exports values of variables when executed. The same values will be used in another script.

```
#!/bin/sh
export I="10"
echo $I
```

I will be using root access for `cron`.
I tried this command:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/backup/.test.sh
```

After it ran, I checked the environment variables, and nothing was updated.

How do I run this script in `cron` and get it to properly export variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export` only makes variables available to sub processes, not to existing shells, or even shells that run later.

Only those called by `test.sh` would see the new environment variables.

While this answers your question, you may want to edit it to describe what you are trying to achieve - why you want to do this, so that you'll get better answers, different approaches.